# Signs in the orthonormal bases

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

What I am trying to figure out is how they got the negative sign in the red circle, because from my calculations (blue circle) I get the first one to negative but the second one, that is the red circled one, is positive; I don't think normalizing would change the sign. What am I doing wrong? I just don't see how the red-circled one can be negative and not the one above it. Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong, or thinking for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that eigenvectors are not unique. Both $(-1,1)$ and $(\frac1{\sqrt2}, -\frac1{\sqrt2})$ are eigenvectors of your matrix to $\lambda = 3$.

In fact if $Ax = \lambda x$, then $Ay = \lambda y$ for any scalar multiple $y$ of $x$. Here $y = -\frac1{\sqrt2}x$ if $y$ is "their" eigenvector and $x$ is "yours".

The convention by wich they arrived at their eigenvectors is to enforce $x_1 \ge 0$ and $\|x\| = 1$ for every eigenvector $x$.

Comment: So, from what I understand, it's safe to assume that even eigenvalue of 1 has an eigenvector where both elements are negative?

Comment: @DickArmstrong Sure. You can even name one of them:
$$-1\cdot\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}} = \pmatrix{-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}}$$

Comment: that just reminded me of a previous example and after fanatically looking for it in my notes I found it, I had the following bases, **s(transpose(-0.5 1))** which was the same thing as **s(transpose(1 -2))**. Thank you!

Comment: @DickArmstrong Indeed. BTW If you want to typeset vectors, have a look at the `\pmatrix` code from my comment.

Comment: still cloudy even on equations, I have bookmarked a few useful posts and pages regarding latex or whatever it's called and hopefully I'll read them one day =P

Comment: Allright. In case you don't have them already: [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation) are posts on this site.